# Parse set ACL on user obejct

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to prevent user to change his own data. 
By default parse give the user permissions to reed and write to his own object.
I want to prevent him the writing.

I tried to run this

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
   var user = request.user;
   if (!user.existed()) {
      var userACL = new Parse.ACL(user);
      userACL.setWriteAccess(user,false);
      user.setACL(userACL);
      user.save();
    }
  });
```

But I dont see that this is change something. their is another option to do this?
This is possible to do this?

Comment: if (request.object.get("username")) {
    throw "your cant change it";
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but you cannot prevent users from access to their own entry in the User table. Its just the way Parse works I believe.

This seems like it would be better placed in a beforeSave anyway :)